# Locking cells after data entry in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to lock cells only if data has been entered. I want to check the range to make sure that the cells are blank prior to locking them. 
The error I am getting is 
"Unable to set Locked property of the Range class".
Sheet is not protected and there are no merged cells either.

```
Sub Locking()
'Lock Cells if data has been entered
    Dim rpcell As Range
    Set rpcell = Range("F2:G26")

With ActiveSheet
    .Unprotect Password:="1234"
    .Cells.Locked = False
    For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If rpcell.Value = "" Then
            rpcell.Locked = False
        Else
            rpcell.Locked = True
        End If
    Next rpcell
    .Protect Password:="1234"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @urdearboy `For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange` will apply the activesheet as the parent.

Comment: Are you trying to loop through the used range or `Range("F2:G26")`? I think that is your issue

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: the code runs fine for me, but the line `Set rpcell = Range("F2:G26")` is immediately overwritten with `For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange`  So it will look at all cells in the used range and not just `F2:G26`.

Comment: If you only want `F2:G26` then use `For Each rpcell In ActiveSheet.Range("F2:G26")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check 1 cell at a time here

```
Dim rpcell as Range

With ActiveSheet

    .Unprotect Password:= "1234"
    .Cells.Locked = False

    For Each rpcell In .Range("F2:G26")
        rpcell.Locked = (rpcell.Value <> "")
    Next rpcell

    .Protect Password:= "1234"

End With
```